# UISearchDisplayController delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, delegates, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to gain some knowledge on UISearchDisplayController and going through some tutorial with examples, I have the below class ready with a search bar and table view with data on it.

***Header file:***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>    
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *suggestionsTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

***Implementation file:***

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface DVWNoteTypeSuggestionDisplayController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic)BOOL isSearching;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredList;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"SuggestionDisplayController" bundle:BUNDLE];

    if (self)
    {
        // Set the title.
        self.title = @"test";
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 38);
    self.suggestionsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    self.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item No. 1", @"Item No. 2", @"Item No. 3", @"Item No. 4", @"Item No. 5", @"Item No. 6", nil];
    self.isSearching = NO;
    self.filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
//    // Return the number of rows in the section.
//    // Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
//    return [self.items count];
//}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.isSearching)
    {
        //If the user is searching, use the list in our filteredList array.
        return [self.filteredList count];
    } else
    {
        return [self.items count];
    }
}

//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//    //Where we configure the cell in each row
//    
//    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//    UITableViewCell *cell;
//    
//    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (cell == nil) {
//        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    }
//    // Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label
//    cell.textLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    return cell;
//}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *title;
    if (self.isSearching && [self.filteredList count]) {
        //If the user is searching, use the list in our filteredList array.
        title = [self.filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else
    {
        title = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = title;

    return cell;
}

- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self.filteredList removeAllObjects]; //clears the array from all the string objects it might contain from the previous searches

    for (NSString *title in self.items) {
        NSRange nameRange = [title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self.filteredList addObject:title];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    //When the user taps the search bar, this means that the controller will begin searching.
    self.isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    //When the user taps the Cancel Button, or anywhere aside from the view.
    self.isSearching = NO;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterListForSearchText:searchString]; // The method we made in step 7

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterListForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]]; // The method we made in step 7

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Whenever I try to search for any items in the data set (eg: "Item No. 5") its not hitting the breakpoints on any of the delegate i.e. actually the search is not working. Please suggest what am I missing here as this is just my learning project right now.

Comment: is self.searchDisplayController == nil ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a `UISearchDisplayController` created programatically in this way is prematurely zeroing the delegate, even though the view controller is retaining the `UISearchDisplayController` as expected.

Add the following to the end of your `viewDidLoad` and you'll see that the first log will be a valid object, but the second will be null.

> NSLog(@"Delegate should be %@", self.searchDisplayController.delegate);
>
> ```
> dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>     NSLog(@"Delegate is %@", self.searchDisplayController.delegate);
> });
> ```

The quickest way I've found to get around this is to store your own reference to the `UISearchDisplayController` via a private property or ivar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create object for search bar controller and set `delegate` search bar its work.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;         
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 38);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Comment: This didn't help me much. However I updated the code displayed here with your suggested code.